# TextBox returns empty String on Button click in Bootstrap modal

Tags: c#, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, webforms

Might be a dummy question, but this issue is getting me mad.

I have a MasterPage that has the main design and of course the `<form runat="server">` tag.

The page I'm currently working on has a bootstrap modal containing a text box and button. I want to get the TextBox text entered by the user in the "***OnClick***" event of the Button. At first button click event wasn't fired so I used Use `UseSubmitBehavior="False"` and the click event is fired finally. Here's the problem, the TextBox returns empty string when I try to get the text in it.

My page's html code :

```
<div id="dlgNewOrder" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div>
                    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
                    <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
                        <ContentTemplate>
                            <div class="container">
                                <div class="row">
                                    <div class="col-md-3">
                                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" CssClass="form-control" EnableViewState="True" ID="txtQuantity" placeholder="Quantity"></asp:TextBox>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div>
                                <br />
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnAddToCart" UseSubmitBehavior="False" Text="Add" CssClass="btn btn-info" />
                        </ContentTemplate>
                    </asp:UpdatePanel>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

And here's the code behind :

```
 void btnAddToCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtQuantity.Text))
        {
            lblErrorMessage.Text = "Error";
        }
        else
        {
            lblErrorMessage.Text = "Correct";
        }

    }
```

Comment: Why did you use EnableViewState="True" ?

Comment: sorry, that was by mistake. Even if it was false or isn't added doesn't affect the bug. The same problem happens.

Comment: Why did you place UseSubmitBehavior="False" from the Button control?

Comment: @abramlimpin Because the ClickEvent of the button wasn't fired and it was fired when I added it.

Comment: You're also missing OnClick='btnAddToCart_Click' from the Button control. Make sure you set the modifier to protected void btnAddToCart_Click

Comment: @abramlimpin I'm firing this event in the Constructor using this code :

Comment: btnAddToCart.Click += btnAddToCart_Click;

Comment: @AbdullahEl-Menawy Did you place the btnAddToCart.Click += btnAddToCart_Click inside the Page_Load event? If so, place it inside if (!IsPostBack)

Comment: Yes, I wrote constructor by mistake but yes, I'm putting it in the Page_Load and not in the !IsPostBack
Would you please try the code if you don't mind ?

Comment: I tried the same code exactly but not in the Bootstrap modal and it worked fine. I really can't figure it out :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be as issue for ASP.NET web forms UpdatePanel with the bootstrap modal.

I tried the jQuery modal and works like a charm! :s